# Building Rpy2 for windows

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I was confused that official `rpy2` last version didn't supported for windows platforms.

I found unofficial building of the last development version on 'lgautier' bitbucket repository  [here](https://bitbucket.org/breisfeld/rpy2_w32_fix/issue/1/binary-installer-for-win32) Building in attachement.

Hope it's usefull for you.